# How to attach an icon to a programming language tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, sponsored-tags

I noticed that there were icons in the programming language tags like [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) and [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart).

What can I do to add one for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)?

Comment: You can't. Only the creators of Python can. [What do icons on the tags mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get in touch with the [Python Software Foundation](https://www.python.org/psf-landing/) and convince them to [advertise here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean).

You might have to organize the neccessary money too... Good luck.